# Personal server solution

Tags: web-server, cloud-storage

Hello and sorry if this question may sound dumb. What I want, is to have a personal Linux server, with just adequate processor power and ram quantity, and fairly large storage (500gb would be good), just to use it as my personal remote machine for any purpose, but mainly to store my files. I do not want SSD disks, as it has no importance, and it will be used by me and 3-4 other people, so no large bandwidth either.

I would like you to point out some suitable service for that, or at least point out what kind of service I should be looking for, as all I can find are business solutions, with SSD disks, too much ram, too many and too powerful cpu's and various bandwidth and total transfer limitations, not at all the kind I am looking for.

EDIT: I am NOT looking for the SOFTWARE the server will contain, I am looking for a suitable service to provide me with an actual or a virtual MACHINE to work on and have access to through the internet.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)

Comment: You are asking for a Linux distro.  Look at https://linuxdistros.org/ or ask on http://unix.stackexchange.com/  Googling for `list of small linux distros` brings some great hits, like https://www.linux.com/news/best-lightweight-linux-distros-2017 and  https://itsfoss.com/lightweight-linux-beginners/  etc, etc, etc

Comment: No I am not looking for a distro - perhaps I now understand why my question is off topic. I am not looking for a server operating system. I am looking about an actual server - an, actual or preferably virtual, machine to operate on from anywhere, and not a homemade solution. But since what I am looking for might as well be at the cloud, I thought software recommendations might have been a good place to ask. I do not know at what other exchange site to ask this on.

Comment: @Izzy Should I delete my question? Can you recommend what other stackexchange site I could possibly transfer this question to?

Comment: @NoobDoob to my knowledge, there currently is no SE site covering that topic – so we cannot transfer your question anywhere.